# Why am I getting "HTTP request Response Assertion:Test failed:text expected to contain /302/" error in "Assertion Results" in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Asked again since I forgot to attach screenshots earlier !

Why am I getting

> **ERROR:** HTTP request Response Assertion:Test failed:text expected to contain /302/

in "Assertion Results" in jmeter?

Please see the attached screenshot:

Comment: There are no attached screen shots. Can you see the response jmeter expected? Did it have the response code you expected?

Comment: Can you show Response Assertion content as long as HTTP Request ? thanks

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK : Can you see the attached screenshots . I'm note sure whether they got attached properly. Thanks

Comment: @JonWolski : Can you see the screenshots now? Thanks

Comment: no I can’t see any screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You most probably didn’t select **Response code** in the field **apply to**.

Regarding what you show:

> www.google.com should be in field "Server Name or IP" not path